Are the etymological "why" questions (for example, about the apparent exceptions to High German Consonant Shift) on-topic?
Thus far, I asked three such questions:

In the German word "Winter" (winter), why didn't the High German Consonant Shift change 't' to 'z' /ts/, so as to be "Winzer"?
Why did 't' shift to 's' in "besser" (compare the English word "better"), but not in "bitter" (compare English "bitter")?
Why did the High German Consonant Shift change the -th in the 3rd person singular present to -t instead of to -d?

On each of those questions, I received comments telling me that they are off-topic. So, are such questions on-topic or off-topic here? Why?

They are all about German language. Hence, I consider them all on-topic.
On the last question, I left a comment myself, but this was not meant to mark the question as off-topic. It is just a general reflection on why-questions and on how to make them more clear.
Some commentators on the other questions mention that those questions would be on-topic on linguistics.stackexchange.com. That might be true, but I consider this irrelevant for the question of whether the question is on-topic here. Questions can be on-topic on both sites, and given the overlap between the topics "German Language" and "Linguistics", I would expect some questions to be on-topic on both sides.
I don't even understand their comments as a discussion about whether the question is on-topic here. I read it as a discussion about regretting migrating the question here from linguistics.stackexchange.com If this is a problem at all, it should be discussed there.
